Scripting with SMO for MS SQL Server very slow for big databases after upgrading from version 150 to 171
We are working with some databases that have really many schemas and tables. We are using SMO (Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects) to script out object creation for separate schemas in these database. For example, now I am looking at a database with 1200 schemas and 75 objects in each schema.
When using SMO version 150.18208.0, scripting one schema takes about 12 seconds on a local SQL Server (much slower using azure sql, but that's another topic). After trying to upgrade to latest SMO, version 171.30.0, this now takes about 2-3 minutes.
Here's how we create our scripter:
            var scripter = new Scripter(sourceDb.SmoServer)
            {
                Options =
                {
                    DriAll = true,
                    Indexes = true,
                    ClusteredIndexes = true,
                    NonClusteredIndexes = true,
                    DriIndexes = true,
                    DriClustered = true,
                    DriNonClustered = true,
                    FullTextIndexes = false,
                    Triggers = true,
                    Default = true,
                    ScriptDataCompression = false,
                    AllowSystemObjects = false,
                    AgentJobId = false,
                    ScriptXmlCompression = false
                }
            };

And here's how we create scripts (allSchemaObjects containing all 75 objects in one schema):
scripts.AddRange( scripter.EnumScript(allSchemaObjects));

What we see in our traces are one statement taking 1.7 seconds like the one below for each of the 75 objects.
Any ideas on how to get back to something near that old performance by using latest SMO version?
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
i.name AS [Name],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_xmax,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxXMax],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_xmin,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxXMin],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_ymax,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxYMax],
CAST(ISNULL(si.bounding_box_ymin,0) AS float(53)) AS [BoundingBoxYMin],
CAST(case when (i.type=7) then hi.bucket_count else 0 end AS int) AS [BucketCount],
CAST(ISNULL(si.cells_per_object,0) AS int) AS [CellsPerObject],
CAST(i.compression_delay AS int) AS [CompressionDelay],
~i.allow_page_locks AS [DisallowPageLocks],
~i.allow_row_locks AS [DisallowRowLocks],

        CASE WHEN ((SELECT tbli.is_memory_optimized FROM sys.tables tbli WHERE tbli.object_id = i.object_id)=1 or
        (SELECT tti.is_memory_optimized FROM sys.table_types tti WHERE tti.type_table_object_id = i.object_id)=1)
        THEN ISNULL((SELECT ds.name FROM sys.data_spaces AS ds WHERE ds.type=''FX''), N'''')
        ELSE CASE WHEN ''FG''=dsi.type THEN dsi.name ELSE N'''' END
        END
       AS [FileGroup],
CASE WHEN ''FD''=dstbl.type THEN dstbl.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileStreamFileGroup],
CASE WHEN ''PS''=dstbl.type THEN dstbl.name ELSE N'''' END AS [FileStreamPartitionScheme],
i.fill_factor AS [FillFactor],
ISNULL(i.filter_definition, N'''') AS [FilterDefinition],
i.ignore_dup_key AS [IgnoreDuplicateKeys],

        ISNULL(indexedpaths.name, N'''')
       AS [IndexedXmlPathName],
i.is_primary_key + 2*i.is_unique_constraint AS [IndexKeyType],
CAST(
          CASE i.type WHEN 1 THEN 0 WHEN 4 THEN 4
                      WHEN 3 THEN CASE xi.xml_index_type WHEN 0 THEN 2 WHEN 1 THEN 3 WHEN 2 THEN 7 WHEN 3 THEN 8 END
                      WHEN 4 THEN 4 WHEN 6 THEN 5 WHEN 7 THEN 6 WHEN 5 THEN 9 ELSE 1 END
        AS tinyint) AS [IndexType],
CAST(CASE i.index_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [IsClustered],
i.is_disabled AS [IsDisabled],
CAST(CASE WHEN filetableobj.object_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS [IsFileTableDefined],
CAST(ISNULL(k.is_system_named, 0) AS bit) AS [IsSystemNamed],
CAST(OBJECTPROPERTY(i.object_id,N''IsMSShipped'') AS bit) AS [IsSystemObject],
i.is_unique AS [IsUnique],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_1_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level1Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_2_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level2Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_3_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level3Grid],
CAST(ISNULL(si.level_4_grid,0) AS smallint) AS [Level4Grid],
ISNULL(s.no_recompute,0) AS [NoAutomaticRecomputation],
CAST(ISNULL(INDEXPROPERTY(i.object_id, i.name, N''IsPadIndex''), 0) AS bit) AS [PadIndex],
ISNULL(xi2.name, N'''') AS [ParentXmlIndex],
CASE WHEN ''PS''=dsi.type THEN dsi.name ELSE N'''' END AS [PartitionScheme],
case UPPER(ISNULL(xi.secondary_type,'''')) when ''P'' then 1 when ''V'' then 2 when ''R'' then 3 else 0 end AS [SecondaryXmlIndexType],
CAST(ISNULL(spi.spatial_index_type,0) AS tinyint) AS [SpatialIndexType],
CAST(ISNULL(INDEXPROPERTY(i.object_id, i.name, N''IsOptimizedForSequentialKey''), 0) AS bit) AS [IsOptimizedForSequentialKey],
CAST(
        case when ((SELECT  MAX(case when xml_compression = 1 then 1 else 0 end) FROM sys.partitions  WHERE object_id = (CASE WHEN i.type = 4 THEN allobj.object_id ELSE i.object_id END) AND index_id = (CASE WHEN i.type = 4 THEN 1 ELSE i.index_id END)) > 0) then 1 else 0 end
       AS bit) AS [HasXmlCompressedPartitions]
FROM
sys.tables AS tbl
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON (i.index_id > @_msparam_0 and i.is_hypothetical = @_msparam_1) AND (i.object_id=tbl.object_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.spatial_index_tessellations as si ON i.object_id = si.object_id and i.index_id = si.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.hash_indexes AS hi ON i.object_id = hi.object_id AND i.index_id = hi.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dsi ON dsi.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = i.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dstbl ON dstbl.data_space_id = t.Filestream_data_space_id and (i.index_id < 2 or (i.type = 7 and i.index_id < 3))
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.xml_indexes AS xi ON xi.object_id = i.object_id AND xi.index_id = i.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.selective_xml_index_paths AS indexedpaths ON xi.object_id = indexedpaths.object_id AND xi.using_xml_index_id = indexedpaths.index_id AND xi.path_id = indexedpaths.path_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.filetable_system_defined_objects AS filetableobj ON i.object_id = filetableobj.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.key_constraints AS k ON k.parent_object_id = i.object_id AND k.unique_index_id = i.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.stats AS s ON s.stats_id = i.index_id AND s.object_id = i.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.xml_indexes AS xi2 ON xi2.object_id = xi.object_id AND xi2.index_id = xi.using_xml_index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.spatial_indexes AS spi ON i.object_id = spi.object_id and i.index_id = spi.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.all_objects AS allobj ON 
        allobj.name = ''extended_index_'' + cast(i.object_id AS varchar) + ''_'' + cast(i.index_id AS varchar) AND allobj.type=''IT''
      
WHERE
(tbl.name=@_msparam_2 and SCHEMA_NAME(tbl.schema_id)=@_msparam_3)
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_1 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_2 nvarchar(4000),@_msparam_3 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'0',@_msparam_1=N'0',@_msparam_2=N'DomainItem_temp',@_msparam_3=N's19'


A comment about my comment about Azure SQL: It appears that the old version of SMO basically does not work towards Azure SQL. When having like 300 schemas in my DB, scripting just hangs forever it looks like. Toards Azure SQL it takes about 25 seconds to script 1 schema. Bumping up to 600 schemas, it takes 45 seconds to script objects in one of them. Not great, but at least it works. Will keep trying to add more schemas to the DB to see how the curve is.
